# mySQL UNION clause with two ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union, fetch

here's the problem
I need to fetch rows from my table where date created is less than 24 hours ago and ORDER them by likes and then UNION them with the rest of rows in the same table but I want the remaining rows to be ORDERED by date created.
in other words I need separate ORDER BY clause for each SELECT.
to be more clear, it's something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM 'table' 
      WHERE 'date_created' > timestampadd(hour, -24, now()) 
      ORDER BY 'likes' DESC 
      UNION 
      SELECT * 
      FROM 'table' 
      WHERE 
      ORDER BY date_created DESC ) AS Results 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

thanks for this awesome community :)

Comment: You're missing the `WHERE` condition in the second subquery.

Comment: You're also using the wrong types of quotes around table and column names. They should be backticks -- single quotes create literal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (date_created > timestampadd(hour, -24, now()) AS recent
FROM table
ORDER BY recent DESC, IF(recent, likes, 0) DESC, IF(!recent, date_created, 0) DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```